# Parsing url inside string

Tags: regex

How would I go about matching the

following string format ( everything after the equal sign to the end of the .html

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomains.com.com%2FSA100.html
```

inside the string below:

```
http://www.tticker.com/me0439-119?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomains.com.com%2FSA100.html%3Fc%2acn%2CSA400
```

Comment: What language are you coding with? Many languages have libraries that easily support the extraction of POST data from URL strings. This method is usually much more accurate than coming up with a regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<==).*?\.html
```

**test with grep**

```
   kent$  echo "http://www.tticker.com/me0439-119?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomains.com.com%2FSA100.html%3Fc%2acn%2CSA400"|grep -Po "(?<==).*?\.html"
    http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomains.com.com%2FSA100.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest I could come up with was:

```
/url=(http.*\.html)/
```

Use the capture group for your URL.

Comment: Bear in mind, it's not perfect. But then again, RegEx shouldn't be used for this type of thing, when most languages let you capture this data.

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use URI;
my $uri = URI->new("http://www.tticker.com/me0439-119?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomains.com.com%2FSA100.html%3Fc%2acn%2CSA400"); # create URI object
my %params = $uri->query_form();                      # get all params
my $param_url = $params{url};

my $uri2 = URI->new($param_url); # create new URI object from param URL  
$uri2->query(undef);             # strip parameters
print $uri2->as_string();
```

gives:

```
http://www.mydomains.com.com/SA100.html
```